# How to erase the data on the tapes of the bacula

Tags: backup, reset, erase, bacula

I'm using bacula as backup tool, but as I am not responsible for the process does not know how to reset the tapes to start over.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `bacula` or what its needs are regarding erasing tapes, but the `normal` way to erase a tape on Linux is:

```
mt -f /dev/????? erase
```

Maybe a physical erase is not what is needed by `bacula` - maybe it needs an entry in a tape management database deleting or resetting. Maybe it needs to have a label written at the start of the tape - which will also erase the rest of the tape's contents.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, but is there any way for me to erase all the tapes?

Comment: How many do you have? Why can't you put them in your tape drive(s) one at a time and run the command above? Or do you need a physical `bulk eraser` machine, also known as a `degausser`?